# Вызов неуправляемого кода из управляемого

Tags: pinvoke, c#

Есть необходимость вызвать функцию WinAPI из кода на C#. Какие средства языка позволяют это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть разные подходы. [Практические рекомендации по взаимодействию управляемого и машинного кода](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd315414.aspx).

Например, если использовать P/Invoke из C#, то это выглядит так:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "Hello, World!", "", 0);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String message, String caption, int options);
    }
}
```