# как в C# подключить си библиотеку?

Tags: c#, linux, c

**Хочу подключить си библиотеки в С# файл, как это сделать ?**

*Пишу код в линуксе (в Убунте с последующем переводе в Дебиан) "собираю" код в MonoDevelop*

вот библиотеки :

```
# include <stdlib.h>

# include <net/if.h>
# include <sys/time.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/ioctl.h>
# include <sys/socket.h>

# include <linux/version.h>
# include <linux/input.h>
# include <linux/can/raw.h>

# include <linux/can.h>
# include <linux/can/bcm.h>
```

Как их подключить ??

На примере `stdlib.h` хочу пояснить зачем их хочу подключить.

```
// подключаю 
#include<stdlib.h>
...
// вызываю функцию создающую КАН подключение 
system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000 ");
```

---

Вот попробовал воспользоваться

```
// вот "простейший" пример, попытка "вызова" СИ библиотеки в СИ-шарп коде. 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// # include <stdio.h> //   подключаем стдио для printf();


class TrimTram1
{
    private static void Main()
    {
    DllImport("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode);
    //  [DllImport("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    printf("Парам пам пам :3");
   }
}
```

вот результат для `[DllImport("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`  :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn3.cs 
tehn3.cs(69,1): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `['
tehn3.cs(69,75): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `]', expecting `;' or `}'
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

вот результат для `DllImport("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode);` :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn3.cs 
tehn3.cs(17,14): warning CS0219: The variable `datchik_t' is assigned but its value is never used
tehn3.cs(69,2): error CS0103: The name `DllImport' does not exist in the current context
tehn3.cs(69,59): error CS0103: The name `CharSet' does not exist in the current context
tehn3.cs(69,49): error CS0103: The name `CharSet' does not exist in the current context
tehn3.cs(70,2): error CS0103: The name `printf' does not exist in the current context
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 1 warnings
```

*П.с. очень поражаюсь количеству минусов НО ПРИ ЭТОМ Я НЕ ПОЛУЧИЛ НЕ одного ответа !!!! Это дно товарищи просто дно :3*

Comment: Вам нужна именно printf из libc, или она только для примера? Для форматного вывода в консоль в C# можно использовать перегрузку Console.Write со списком аргументов: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=netcore-2.2#System_Console_Write_System_String_System_Object___

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов неуправляемого кода из управляемого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight дело в том что перевожу код с СИ на СИ-шарп. И там есть библиотека именно сетевая я ей вызывал через команду `system` вызываю сетевое соединение.

Comment: @timob256 Конкретно для system тоже есть родной аналог в C# - [Process.Start](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-1.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_). Попробуйте для вашего примера так: `Process.Start("ip", "link set can0 type can bitrate 125000");`

Comment: А вот для других функции из linux/can.h аналогов не будет, надо думать, как подключать. Приведите примеры пары функций, которые вы хотите вызывать (лучше всего прототипы из .h файла в вопрос добавить).

Answer (score 3):

Всё просто: атрибут [DllImport](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=netframework-4.8) позволит вам вызывать unmanaged-методы с помощью технологии P/Invoke.

---

EDIT: Вы должны создать unmanaged-dll библиотеку, чтобы использовать этот атрибут (с `.h` или `.lib` форматами он не работает - только `.dll`).

Comment: Ничего что в вопросе линукс?

Comment: @Qwertiy Извините, сразу пошёл писать ответ, толком не вглядываясь в код. К сожалению, на линуксе не работаю и помочь не могу

Comment: @Qwertiy все же верно, вроде, ну, да, в Linux не dll, а so, но P/Invoke там работает также прекрасно, как и на Windows, хотя, наверное, dll в ответе стоило бы заменить просто на библиотеку.

Comment: @return это вы меня извините, забыл упомянуть,   работаю в линуксе (Убунте с послед переносом в Дебиан) а собираю код монодевелопером

Comment: Увы но можно увидеть пример ??